# AngularJS Search by display value instead of received data/json value?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am following the tutorial Codepen example here to do Angularjs search on table:

https://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/AmFLE

Let's say the tastiness numbers that I am receiving from server are like 255, 65551, 32322 , where the last two digits are supposed to be decimals.

So in order to display them in comprehensive way for user, i did on html:

```
{{ roll.tastiness/100 | number : 2}}
```

in the table:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish">
    <td>{{ roll.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ roll.fish }}</td>
    <td>{{ roll.tastiness/100 | number : 2}}</td>
```

Note that I didn't modify the code in codepen because it's not mine, but you can try the modifications there.

and I changed the data value in controller (again, without saving the codepen) to this:

```
  $scope.sushi = [
    { name: 'Cali Roll', fish: 'Crab', tastiness: 255 },
    { name: 'Philly', fish: 'Tuna', tastiness: 466 },
    { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Eel', tastiness: 7 },
    { name: 'Rainbow', fish: 'Variety', tastiness: 6 }
  ];
```

The issue is, that even though the numbers are being displayed like 2.55 and 4.66, in the search i have to put 255 instead of 2.55 in order to find the record.

What should I do in order to make the search detects the values as how they're displayed on page  instead of the values as presented in $scope.sushi array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the filter is filtering on the actual values and the pipe is transforming those values for display only. The values the filter is working on stayed the same, without the decimal places.

You can modify the search filter or modify the values. It depends do you need to keep the same values for some other purposes. If not I would go for modifying the values and removing the pipe.

Lowest level vanilla here compatibile with all JS versions is simple for loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<sushi.length; i++){
  sushi[i].tastiness = sushi[i].tastiness/100;
}
```

Execute BEFORE displaying. And remove pipe when displaying.

Comment: hmm so if I don't want to modify $scope.sushi that much, the safest way would be to create another parallel array of objects like `$scope.displaySushi = []`  and apply the loop as you suggested and saving the new values to be displayed to that new array, and then i do `ng-repeat ="roll in displaySushi"`

Comment: I would use angular.copy() to make a deep copy of an array and then run for loop over that array. Or you can fill it with that loop that is changing the tastiness, just make sure to copy the entire object not just tastiness.. For angular.copy - here is the doc  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>{{ roll.tastiness/100 | number : 2}}</td>
```

Angular JS with use of PIpe only modifies UI display value but your JSON value is still 255 only that is why it is not searching with 2.55 
I think while filter just provide same PIPE logic values so that i t can did search properly